# Counting game strategy

Tags: game-theory, algorithmic-game-theory

Assume two players play against each other, and assume the initial number the game start  with is 1.
Each turn a player can add 1 or add 2 or multiply by 2.

Goal: The winner is the player who reaches the number T (and above).

Is there a **global** winning strategy for a random number T?

When trying to solve private examples the strategy seems to change each time, for example when T=100 or T=103.

Comment: What is the goal of the game?

Comment: @GregMartin oops, I edited the post.

Comment: If it is prohibited for the running total to exceed $T$, computations indicate that the game is a second-player win when $T\equiv1\pmod3$ and a first-player win otherwise. But it seems you intended that making the running total larger than $T$ also wins the game; in this case, computations indicate thatwhen $T\ge4$, the game is a second-player win when $T\equiv3,4\pmod6$ and a first-player win otherwise.